# Jenkins - global state for stage re-run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a *Jenkinsfile* in order to define my *Jenkins pipeline*. 
I've defined some global variables, to save/pass information between *stages*.

When a re-run of a specific stage is performed, the global variables (defined in the *Jenkinsfile*, outside the *pipeline*, using the `def` keyword) are re-initialized and the state is lost.

Which of *Jenkins*' mechanisms allows storing state/data for a situation of a single stage re-run? (except for binary artifacts -- it just seems like the wrong solution for storing variables)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To my knowledge there is no good solution to this so far. The root cause is that builds are considered independent of each other. However, the real question is what's the content of the data you want to preserve between two executions. From a first glance (and my the year-long experience), it feels wrong trying to do that. So, could you please elaborate a little more on what and why you want to store references/data?

Comment: @EagleRainbow thanks! The information I want to pass between steps is mainly git related stuff and boolean values representing whether previous steps were actually skipped. (due to a pre-defined condition, which causes some stages to be skipped)

Comment: Please elaborate why you cannot redetermine the boolean flags each time the pipeline is run. Note that "passing between steps" is possible for example using global variables within groovy/Jenkinsfile. Only passing between builds of jobs is tricky...